# How to stop AutoCompleteTextView from displaying suggestions when activity onResume() gets called?

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview

In my application one of the activity has two `AutoCompleteTextView`. I select values from suggestion list for both of them and press OK button .OK button leads to me a new activity for showing results basis of the AutoCompleteTextView values .But if I now presses back button and return to the activity that has two AutoCompleteTextView Textview, they both start showing suggestions list.I want them not to show suggestion list as the suggestion list contains only single item the one that's already in textViews. I tried to set adapter NULL and then set back to original array, but that doesn't stop AutoCompleteTextView from showing suggestion list.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.find_path);
        initializeElements();
        GetAllPathList();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Path>(this, R.layout.dropdown_list_item,
                pathArray);
        startPathAutocomplete.setAdapter(adapter);
        endPathAutocomplete.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

> ```
> public class Path {
>
>   private String _id;
>   private String pathName;
>   private String pathLine;
>
>   public Station(String _id, String pathName, String pathLine) {
>       this._id = _id;
>       this.pathName= pathName;
>           this.pathLine = pathLine;
>   }
> //getter setter methods for variables
>
> }
> ```

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        stationArray = null;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: you should set ArrayList NULL for this

Comment: @DixitPatel set the ArrayList to null in Activity's onResume() method, but the suggestion list is still showing up.What could be the problem?

Comment: post your full code here..

Comment: When you come back from another activity the **onResume()** is being called. So set the arrayAdapter null in onResume(). And you can use this method `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` on your arrayAdapter.

Comment: Just create two adapter to solve this problem

Comment: @DixitPatel you mean one with NULL and other one with original values? Or something else?

Comment: you create two seprate adapter they both having same items

Comment: How does this solve my issue?

Comment: Before set adapter you have to set thresold value for autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you come back from another `Activity` **onResume()** method is been called. So whatever you want to set to your `Adapter` you should set it in **onResume()** method. And just notify your adapter that the data has been changed. Thats it :)

**EDITED** Thinking of pathArray and stationArray are same

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    stationArray = null;
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Path>(this, R.layout.dropdown_list_item,
            stationArray);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    startPathAutocomplete.setAdapter(adapter);
    endPathAutocomplete.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code according to you...but its still not working